# Does adding an odd function to the numerator of an even function integrand, keep the value of the integral (over $(-\infty,\infty)$) same?

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the Integral:

> $$\mathrm\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{[x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1]}dx\\$$
>
> Where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary constant

My book says : *Since this is an even function, adding an odd function to the numerator will  not change the integral*

Therefore  this integral can be written as:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1}{[x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1]}dx\\$$

> **What I understand:** I know and understand that the integrand of the integral I am trying to evaluate is Even.

What I don't understand is that why adding an odd function to the numerator won't change the integral, and how is this valid?

**My thoughts:**

I know for an odd function: $$\int_{-a}^{a} f_o(x) dx=0$$

And  I can write what the book says as :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{[x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1]}dx$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{[x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1]}dx -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2x\sin\alpha}{[x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1]}dx$$

---

But , how do we know that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2x\sin\alpha}{[x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1]}dx$$

is **ODD?** ,

because this integrand is of the form: $$\frac{f_o(x)}{g_e(x)}$$

Comment: An odd function divided by an even function is again odd, for if $f$ is odd and $g$ is even then $(f/g)(-x) = f(-x)/g(-x) = (-f(x))/g(x) = - (f/g)(x)$.

Comment: @Alqatrkapa Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle H(x)=\frac{2x\sin\alpha}{[x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1]},$

$$H(-x)=\frac{2(-x)\sin\alpha}{[(-x)^2-2(-x)\sin\alpha+1][(-x)^2+2(-x)\sin\alpha+1]}$$

$$=\frac{-2x\sin\alpha}{[x^2+2x\sin\alpha+1][x^2-2x\sin\alpha+1]}=-H(x)$$